# Arreglo de MYSQL no muestra un parametro con INNER JOIN

Tags: php, html, mysql, join, inner

Tengo una base de datos de productos y categorias. En la sección de mostrar tengo un INNER JOIN para que me tome el id de categoría y lo guarde en categoria_id de productos.

La función para mostrar toda la información de los productos se ve así.

```
public function mostrar(){

    //relacionar
    $sql ="SELECT productos.id, productos.nombre, productos.descripcion, productos.imagen, precio, productos.fecha, xs, s, m, l, xl, 2xl, 3xl FROM productos
    INNER JOIN categorias
    ON productos.categoria_id = categorias.id ORDER BY productos.id DESC";

    $resultado=$this->cn->prepare($sql);
    
    if($resultado->execute())
    return $resultado->fetchAll();
    return false;
}
```

Al momento de crear un producto puedo observar que los datos se guardan correctamente en cada elemento del arreglo. Por ejemplo:

```
Array
(
    [nombre] => Camisa
    [descripcion] => Descipcion de la camisa
    [precio] => 10
    [categoria_id] => 1
    [imagen] => 5401589.png
    [fecha] => 2021-12-07
    [xs] => 1
    [s] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [l] => 0
    [xl] => 0
    [2xl] => 0
    [3xl] => 0
)
```

[image: Se puede ver que aparece en el portal] (Cabe destacar que pretendo idear todo para ser manejado directamente desde la pagina web sin tener que entrar ahí)

Sin embargo cuando quiero mandar a llamar toda la información de un producto, no me aparece el apartado de categoria_id.

```
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';


 if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
    
 $id=$_GET['id'];
 $producto = new ameri\Producto;
 $categoria = new ameri\Categoria;

 $info_producto=$producto->mostrarPorId($id);
 $info_categoria=$categoria->mostrar();


 print '<pre>';
 print_r($info_producto);
```

Con esto me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [0] => 11
            [nombre] => Camisa
            [1] => Camisa
            [descripcion] => Descipcion de la camisa
            [2] => Descipcion de la camisa
            [imagen] => 5401589.png
            [3] => 5401589.png
            [precio] => 10
            [4] => 10
            [fecha] => 2021-12-07
            [5] => 2021-12-07
            [xs] => 1
            [6] => 1
            [s] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [m] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [l] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [xl] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [2xl] => 0
            [11] => 0
            [3xl] => 0
            [12] => 0
        )
}
```

Como se puede ver no aparece 'categoria_id' como parte del arreglo por lo que me sale este error:

```
Warning:  Undefined array key "categoria_id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\Indoff Pro Website\Template\_filtros-categorias.php on line 21
```

A que se deberá?

Cabe resaltar que cuandoutilizo la función de mostrarPorId con el parámetro $id si aparece

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [0] => 1
    [nombre] => Camisa 1
    [1] => Camisa 1
    [descripcion] =>     kmkmkkm    
    [2] =>     kmkmkkm    
    [imagen] => 51ZljGMg9aL._AC_UX385_.jpg
    [3] => 51ZljGMg9aL._AC_UX385_.jpg
    [precio] => 10
    [4] => 10
    [categoria_id] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [fecha] => 2021-11-29
    [6] => 2021-11-29
    [xs] => 1
    [7] => 1
    [s] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [9] => 0
    [l] => 0
    [10] => 0
    [xl] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [2xl] => 0
    [12] => 0
    [3xl] => 0
    [13] => 0
)
```

Pero esta no me funciona porque solo me mostrará la info de un producto en especifico cuando quiero desplegar todos los que pertenecen a una categoria.

Esta es la funcion

```
  public function mostrarPorId($id){
        $sql ="SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE `id` = :id";

        $resultado=$this->cn->prepare($sql);
        
        
$_array=array(
    ":id" => $id
);
      
        
        if($resultado->execute($_array))
        return $resultado->fetch();
        return false;

    }

}
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que el **INNER JOIN** llama a otra tabla pero no significa que traiga esos datos, debes llamarlos en tu *select* a la hora de ejecutar tu Query.

Primero, no te muestra **categoria_id** porque en tu *select* no lo llamas, solo llamas *productos.id, productos.nombre, productos.descripcion, productos.imagen, precio, productos.fecha, xs, s, m, l, xl, 2xl, 3xl* debes agregar **categoria.id** para que te funcione y te imprima el dato.

Te debe quedar algo así:

```
$sql ="SELECT categorias.id,productos.id, productos.nombre, productos.descripcion, productos.imagen, precio, productos.fecha, xs, s, m, l, xl, 2xl, 3xl FROM productos
    INNER JOIN categorias
    ON productos.categoria_id = categorias.id ORDER BY productos.id DESC";
```

Comment: Hola, gracias. Lo intenté pero aún así no me la muestra :((

Comment: Que raro, puedes colocar tus tablas aca https://www.db-fiddle.com/ para poder trabajar con esa misma estructura, si deseas coloca solo datos de prueba